Getting DelegatingWsConfiguration proxy issue error
I'm developing a Spring Boot application. It's working fine in my local system and able to create data but in dev environment it's not working. Can anyone help me on this issue?
issue : [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0d9a8e4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Since I'm new to Spring Boot and not aware how can I resolve this issue.

As of https://www.baeldung.com/spring-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying you should add @Lazy annotation somewhere in class implementing BeanPostProcessor
